# Cómo uso GetX en InitState para armar una lista en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Cómo se arma una lista en el InitState con Getx estando en un StateFulWidget?

Estoy implementando este package https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists y estoy trabajando en el ejemplo https://github.com/philip-brink/DragAndDropLists/blob/master/example/lib/list_tile_example.dart

En este ejemplo, arman la lista en el InitState, hasta ahí todo bien.

No he sabido implementar Getx a este ejemplo.

Qué necesito hacer?

Este es el ejemplo:

```
import 'package:drag_and_drop_lists/drag_and_drop_lists.dart';
import 'package:example/navigation_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListTileExample extends StatefulWidget {
const ListTileExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
  State createState() => _ListTileExample();  
}

class _ListTileExample extends State<ListTileExample> {
late List<DragAndDropList> _contents;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

_contents = List.generate(4, (index) {
  return DragAndDropList(
    header: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Header $index',
          ),
          subtitle: Text('Header $index subtitle'),
        ),
        const Divider(),
      ],
    ),
    footer: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const Divider(),
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Footer $index',
          ),
          subtitle: Text('Footer $index subtitle'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    children: <DragAndDropItem>[
      DragAndDropItem(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Sub $index.1',
          ),
           trailing: const Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
      ),
    ], 
  );
});
}
```

En el InitState arman la lista que se va a mostrar.

En Getx cómo se hace?

Este es mi controlador:

```
class CrController extends GetxController {
Rx<List<CrModel>> crList = Rx<List<CrModel>>([]);

List<CrModel> get crs => crList.value;

void filterCr(String cr) {
  List<CrModel> results = [];
  if (cr.isEmpty) {
      results = crList.value;
    } else {
      results = crList.value
        .where((element) => element.cr
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .contains(cr.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    }
    crList.value = results;
  }
}
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
class crModel {
crModel({
  required this.id,
  required this.iSp,
  required this.cr,
});

late final String id;
late final String iSp;
late final String cr;
factory crModel.fromJson(String str) =>
  crModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));
  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());
factory crModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => crModel(
  id: json['id'], iSp: json["iSp"], cr: json["cr"]);

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
  "iSp": iSp,
  "cr": cr,
};

crModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(
    {required DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot}) {
    id = documentSnapshot.id;
    cr = documentSnapshot['cr'];
    iSp = documentSnapshot["iSp"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetX posee un método similar para usar llamadas al momento de inicializar.

```
class CrController extends GetxController {
Rx<List<CrModel>> crList = Rx<List<CrModel>>([]);

List<CrModel> get crs => crList.value;

@override
  void onInit() async {
    // TODO: Aqui puedes realizar las operaciones necesarias.
    super.onInit();
  }

void filterCr(String cr) {
  List<CrModel> results = [];
  if (cr.isEmpty) {
      results = crList.value;
    } else {
      results = crList.value
        .where((element) => element.cr
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .contains(cr.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    }
    crList.value = results;
  }
}
```

Ya luego solo debes instanciar el **CrController** en tu pantalla.